# How to solve content.Keywords.key_words: (fields.E005) 'choices' must be an iterable containing (actual value, human readable name) tuples

Tags: python, django, django-models

So I wrote My first ChoiceFIeld Model I facing Some Isuues :

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils import timezone
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _


class Keywords(models.Model):
    POLITICS = 'politics',
    SPORTS = 'sports',
    ENTERTAINMENT = 'entertainment',
    FOOD = 'food',
    LIFESTYLE = 'lifestyle',
    RANDOM = 'random',

    TOPIC = [
        (POLITICS, _('News About Politics')),
        (SPORTS, _('News About Sports')),
        (ENTERTAINMENT, _('News About Entertainment')),
        (FOOD, _('News About Food')),
        (LIFESTYLE, _('News About Lifestyle')),
        (RANDOM, _('Random News')),
    ]

    key_words = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=TOPIC, default=RANDOM,)
```

This is the code i wrote.

But when I am trying to makemigrations It gives me this error?message:

> content.Keywords.key_words: (fields.E005) 'choices' must be an iterable containing (actual value, human readable name) tuples.

What I did wrong?

Thanks Good People.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change to tuple.

```
TOPIC = (
    ('POLITICS', _('News About Politics')),
)
```

Comment: It's same after changing it to tuples. Same error I am facing.